# How is NLog setting the LoggerName?

Tags: .net, logging, .net-core, nlog

I'm having an interesting, apparently temporal, issue with NLog or perhaps the way I'm using it.

I'm attempting to create a logging service abstraction, for the purposes of avoiding hard dependencies, and I've modelled my abstraction on the `NLog.FluentBuilder` class. So I have a pair of interfaces:

```
public interface ILog
    {
    IFluentLogBuilder Trace([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null);
    IFluentLogBuilder Debug([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null);
    IFluentLogBuilder Info([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null);
    IFluentLogBuilder Warn([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null);
    IFluentLogBuilder Error([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null);
    IFluentLogBuilder Fatal([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null);
    void Shutdown();
    }

public interface IFluentLogBuilder
    {
    IFluentLogBuilder Exception(Exception exception);
    IFluentLogBuilder LoggerName(string loggerName);
    IFluentLogBuilder Message(string message);
    IFluentLogBuilder Message(string format, params object[] args);
    IFluentLogBuilder Message(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args);
    IFluentLogBuilder Property(string name, object value);
    IFluentLogBuilder Properties(IDictionary<string,object> properties);
    IFluentLogBuilder TimeStamp(DateTime timeStamp);
    IFluentLogBuilder StackTrace(StackTrace stackTrace, int userStackFrame);
    void Write([CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null, [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null,
        [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = default);
    void WriteIf(Func<bool> condition, [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null,
        [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null, [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = default);
    void WriteIf(bool condition, [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null,
        [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null, [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = default);
    }
```

The idea is to be able to create adapters for different logging frameworks, and of course the first one I've made is for NLog, since that's what I intend to use. The implementation is essentially a pared-down clone of the fluent interface from NLog, so here's a partial abstraction of my version:

#### The `ILog` implementation

```
    public sealed class LoggingService : ILog
        {
        private static readonly ILogger DefaultLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        static LoggingService()
            {
            LogManager.AutoShutdown = true;
            }

        public IFluentLogBuilder Trace([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null)
            {
            return CreateLogBuilder(LogLevel.Trace, callerFilePath);
            }

        // Methods for other log levels elided for clarity...

        private IFluentLogBuilder CreateLogBuilder(LogLevel logLevel, string callerFilePath)
            {
            string name = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(callerFilePath)
                ? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(callerFilePath)
                : null;
            var logger = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) ? DefaultLogger : LogManager.GetLogger(name);
            var builder = new LogBuilder(logger, logLevel);
            return builder;
            }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void Shutdown() => LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
```

#### The `IFluentLogBuilder` implementation

```
    internal sealed class LogBuilder : IFluentLogBuilder
    {
        private readonly LogEventInfo logEvent;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public LogBuilder(ILogger logger, LogLevel level)
        {
            if (logger == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            if (level == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(level));
            this.logger = logger;
            logEvent = new LogEventInfo { LoggerName = logger.Name, Level = level };
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IFluentLogBuilder Exception(Exception exception)
        {
            logEvent.Exception = exception;
            return this;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IFluentLogBuilder LoggerName(string loggerName)
        {
            logEvent.LoggerName = loggerName;
            return this;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IFluentLogBuilder Message(string message)
        {
            logEvent.Message = message;
            return this;
        }

        // Some other builder methods elided for clarity... (they all follow the pattern).

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void Write([CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null,
            [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null,
            [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = default)
        {
            if (!logger.IsEnabled(logEvent.Level)) return;
            SetCallerInfo(callerMemberName, callerFilePath, callerLineNumber);
            logger.Log(logEvent);
        }

        private void SetCallerInfo(string callerMethodName, string callerFilePath, int callerLineNumber)
        {
            if (callerMethodName != null || callerFilePath != null || callerLineNumber != 0)
                logEvent.SetCallerInfo(null, callerMethodName, callerFilePath, callerLineNumber);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Builds and returns the <see cref="LogEventInfo"/> without writing it to the log.
        /// </summary>
        internal LogEventInfo Build() => logEvent;
    }
```

I've left out some of the methods that don't add any extra information to the issue, basically they
all follow the same pattern. This is all very similar, but not identical, to what is in the `NLog.Fluent.LogBuilder` class.

So noe it gets interesting.

#### The Test Program

I included a .NET Core 3.0 console app as a sample program in my library.

I've reproduced this in its entirety, but without the copious comments, which would just get
in the way here.

The program just counts up to 1000, printing out each number as it goes, and producing some
exceptions to make things more interesting and demonstrate semantic logging.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TA.Utils.Core;

namespace TA.Utils.Logging.NLog.SampleConsoleApp
    {
    class Program
        {
        static readonly List<int> SuperstitiousNumbers = new List<int> {13, 7, 666, 3, 8, 88, 888};

        async static Task Main(string[] args)
            {
            var log = new LoggingService();
            log.Info()
                .Message("Application stating - version {Version}", GitVersion.GitInformationalVersion)
                .Property("SemVer", GitVersion.GitFullSemVer)
                .Property("GitCommit", GitVersion.GitCommitSha)
                .Property("CommitDate", GitVersion.GitCommitDate)
                .Write();
            var seed = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
            var gameOfChance = new Random(seed);
            log.Debug().Property("seed",seed).Write();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                try
                    {
                    log.Debug().Message("Starting iteration {iteration}", i).Write();
                    if (SuperstitiousNumbers.Contains(i))
                        {
                        throw new SuperstitiousNumberException($"Skipping {i} because it is a superstitious number");
                        }

                    // There's a small chance of a random "failure"
                    if (gameOfChance.Next(100) < 3)
                        throw new ApplicationException("Random failure");
                    }
                catch (SuperstitiousNumberException ex)
                    {
                    log.Warn()
                        .Message("Superstitious looking number: {number}", i)
                        .Exception(ex)
                        .Property("SuperstitiousNumbers", SuperstitiousNumbers)
                        .Write();
                    }
                catch (ApplicationException ae)
                    {
                    log.Error().Exception(ae).Message("Failed iteration {iteration}", i).Write();
                    }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
                log.Debug().Message("Finished iteration {iteration}", i).Write();
                }
            log.Info().Message("Program terminated").Write();
            log.Shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
```

This program produces the following log output.

```
00:01:09.4823 | INFO  | LogBuilder                      | Application stating - version "1.1.1-beta.1+18.Branch.hotfix-1.1.1.Sha.8b8fa5a008c35d4fc21c99d0bd9a01f6d32c9a53"
00:01:09.5339 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      |
00:01:09.5339 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 0
00:01:10.5636 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 0
00:01:10.5636 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 1
00:01:11.5762 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 1
00:01:11.5762 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 2
00:01:12.5893 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 2
00:01:12.5893 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 3
00:01:12.5893 | WARN  | LogBuilder                      | Superstitious looking number: 3
00:01:13.6325 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 3
00:01:13.6325 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 4
00:01:14.6484 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 4
00:01:14.6484 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 5
00:01:15.6534 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 5
00:01:15.6534 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 6
00:01:16.6653 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 6
00:01:16.6653 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 7
00:01:16.6653 | WARN  | LogBuilder                      | Superstitious looking number: 7
00:01:17.6787 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 7
00:01:17.6787 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 8
00:01:17.6787 | WARN  | LogBuilder                      | Superstitious looking number: 8
00:01:18.6890 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 8
00:01:18.6890 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 9
00:01:19.6926 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 9
00:01:19.6935 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 10
00:01:20.7071 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 10
00:01:20.7071 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 11
00:01:21.7110 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 11
00:01:21.7110 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 12
00:01:22.7367 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 12
00:01:22.7404 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 13
00:01:22.7404 | WARN  | LogBuilder                      | Superstitious looking number: 13
00:01:23.7621 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Finished iteration 13
00:01:23.7621 | DEBUG | LogBuilder                      | Starting iteration 14
00:01:24.7756 | DEBUG | Program                         | Finished iteration 14
00:01:24.7756 | DEBUG | Program                         | Starting iteration 15
00:01:25.7876 | DEBUG | Program                         | Finished iteration 15
00:01:25.7876 | DEBUG | Program                         | Starting iteration 16
00:01:26.8040 | DEBUG | Program                         | Finished iteration 16
00:01:26.8040 | DEBUG | Program                         | Starting iteration 17
00:01:27.8176 | DEBUG | Program                         | Finished iteration 17
00:01:27.8176 | DEBUG | Program                         | Starting iteration 18
00:01:28.8277 | DEBUG | Program                         | Finished iteration 18
00:01:28.8277 | DEBUG | Program                         | Starting iteration 19
00:01:29.8372 | DEBUG | Program                         | Finished iteration 19
00:01:29.8372 | DEBUG | Program                         | Starting iteration 20
```

So here's the beef. Why does the source name change from `LogBuilder` to `Program` half way through iteration 14? Why was it ever `LogBuilder`?

One question I asked myself is: "does it always change at the same place" and the answer is no. It varies by plus or minus one iteration.

My guess is that it could be something to do with the buffering log target that I'm using... here's my `NLog.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       autoReload="true">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.Seq"/>
  </extensions>

  <targets async="true" >
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="console"
            layout="${time} | ${pad:padding=-5:inner=${uppercase:${level}}} | ${pad:padding=-31:inner=${callsite:className=true:fileName=false:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false:includeNamespace=false}} | ${message}" >
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Debug" foregroundColor="DarkGreen" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Info" foregroundColor="White" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Warn" foregroundColor="Yellow" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Error" foregroundColor="Red" />
      <highlight-row condition="level == LogLevel.Fatal" foregroundColor="Red" backgroundColor="White" />
    </target>

    <target name="seq" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="1000"
            flushTimeout="500" slidingTimeout="false">
      <target xsi:type="Seq" name="seq" serverUrl="http://seq.nowhere.com:5341" apiKey="imnotfallingforthatone">
        <!-- Augment the log data with some extra properties -->
        <property name="ProcessId" value="${processid}" />
        <property name="ProcessName" value="${processname}" />
        <property name="ThreadId" value="${threadid}" as="number" />
        <property name="Machine" value="${machinename}" />
        <property name="Host" value="${hostname}" />
        <property name="User" value="${environment-user}" />
      </target>
    </target>

    <target xsi:type="Trace" name="debug" rawWrite="true">
      <layout>${pad:padding=-5:inner=${uppercase:${level}}}|${pad:padding=-16:fixedLength=true:alignmentOnTruncation=right:inner=${callsite:className=true:fileName=false:includeSourcePath=false:methodName=false:includeNamespace=false}}| ${message}</layout>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debug" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="seq" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I would appreciate any insights you are able to give. FYI the [project is open-source](https://github.com/Tigra-Astronomy/TA.Utilities) if you'd like to clone it and examine it in your IDE.

Comment: I think the issue might be related to the fact that my main method was declared `public static async Task Main()`. Replacing `async Task` with `void` and removing the `await` from later in the method gives more deterministic results. I don't fully understand this yet but it definitely seems to be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger name is created a follows:

- When using `Logger.GetLogger(string name)` the name is used without changes
- When using `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` the name of the class is searched on the stacktrace. In some cases this could be tricky, as inlining and async tricks makes it hard to find the correct name.

In this case the usage of `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` isn't really needed and I recommend to replace that one with `Logger.GetLogger(string name)`

Please also note that your design of the fluent API is a bit unconventional - at least for the added properties in your example.

- There is already a fluent interface, see [NLog.Fluent namespace](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/T_NLog_Fluent_LogBuilder.htm)
- Some properties would be better to add to the a context class (e.g. GDC, MDLC, see [context in NLog](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/context)) or added as a [custom layout renderer](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer)

Comment: That's a good suggestion to use `Logger.GetLogger` I will do that. I know about the NLog fluent interface, I'm a big fan, but I need to not have a dependency on NLog for a library. Hence why I'm creating an abstract interface that might look somewhat similar to the NLog fluent interface ;-) Why do you say mine is "unconventional"? I modelled it on the NLog fluent interface so I'm not quite sure what you mean by that...?

Comment: I meant unconventional for the example, some properties would be better on the GDC etc? (2nd bullet).

Comment: Ah OK, I see what you mean. Since I posted the question, I've actually already added a couple members on my `ILog` interface, one of which is called `WithAmbientProperty` so I guess we sort of had the same thoughts there. It's definitely useful to be able to have global properties. I'm logging to Seq and I'm also using the config file to add stuff like the process ID and computer name. This is my first foray into proper structured logging, although I've used NLog for years, and I can't believe I haven't done it sooner!

Comment: Oh, also, I found that if I render the `${logger}` property instead of the `${callsite-whatever}` stuff, then I get reliable results. The call site doesn't seem to get populated consistently when using the fluent interface. I guess that does make sense in hindsight, especially with async/await thrown into the mix.

Comment: @TimLong NLog 5 will improve support for callsite logic from caller-member-attributes. Removing the overhead from doing StackTrace capture.